# Zend pdo_oci and pdo_mysql generating different query formats

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, zend-framework

Oracle DB Adapter: "**pdo_oci**"
MySQL DB Adapter: "**pdo_mysql**"

Code used to build a JOIN query:

```
            $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
            $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);

            $select = $db->select()->from(array(
                   't1' => $this->_Table1
            ));
            $select = $select->join(array(
                   't2' => $this->_Table2
           ), 't1.MENU_ID = t2.SUBMENU_ID',
            array(
                    'MENU_ID',
                    'SET_REDIRECT_URL',
                    'SUBMENU_TYPE'
            ));
            $select = $select->order(array(
                    'MENU_ID',
                    't2.DISPLAY_ORDER'
            ));
            $select = $select->where('t1.IS_ACTIVE = ?', 'Y');
            $result = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

**Query Generated by Oracle Adapter (pdo_oci):**

```
SELECT "t1".*, "t2"."MENU_ID" AS "parent_id", "t2"."SET_REDIRECT_URL", "t2"."SUBMENU_TYPE" FROM "DRP_ADMIN_MENU_MASTER" "t1"  INNER JOIN "DRP_ADMIN_MENU_MAPPER" "t2" ON t1.MENU_ID = t2.SUBMENU_ID WHERE (t1.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y') ORDER BY "parent_id" ASC, "t2"."DISPLAY_ORDER" ASC
```

**Query Generated by Mysql Adapter (pdo_mysql):**

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.`MENU_ID` AS `parent_id`, `t2`.`SET_REDIRECT_URL`, `t2`.`SUBMENU_TYPE` FROM `DRP_ADMIN_MENU_MASTER` AS `t1`  INNER JOIN `DRP_ADMIN_MENU_MAPPER` AS `t2` ON t1.MENU_ID = t2.SUBMENU_ID WHERE (t1.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y') ORDER BY `parent_id` ASC, `t2`.`DISPLAY_ORDER` ASC
```

Issue: Oracle DB is unable to identify t1 and t2 in [t1.MENU_ID = t2.SUBMENU_ID] unless they are in double quotes. And if I put double quotes manually, then mysql gives error.

Error in Oracle:

> General error: 904 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00904: "T2"."SUBMENU_ID":
>   invalid identifier

Comment: It's been a while since I used ZFW, but have you tried using 'T2' instead of 't2' in the code?  Or did the tables get created with case-sensitive, lowercase names?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Used $db->quoteIdentifier(). and it worked

```
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);

        $select = $db->select()->from(array(
               't1' => $this->_Table1
        ));
        $select = $select->join(array(
               't2' => $this->_Table2
       ), $db->quoteIdentifier('t1.MENU_ID') . ' = ' . $db->quoteIdentifier('t2.SUBMENU_ID'),
        array(
                'MENU_ID',
                'SET_REDIRECT_URL',
                'SUBMENU_TYPE'
        ));
        $select = $select->order(array(
                'MENU_ID',
                't2.DISPLAY_ORDER'
        ));
        $select = $select->where($db->quoteIdentifier('t1.IS_ACTIVE') . ' = ?', 'Y');
        $result = $db->fetchAll($select);
```